Have Task Scheduler run a killable program without showing a
There is a program I need to run using Task Scheduler. This program creates a filesystem mount and handles the relevant filesystem operations. However, when I start the task, it opens a command prompt window. This is not what I want to see.
Run whether logged on or not is NOT a solution to this and breaks other things. I've searched around and some people have told question askers to start their desired program from a VBScript. This is not good, however, because ending the task does no longer closes the filesystem program that I am trying to have run.
How can I get my desired program to be run by Task Scheduler without opening a window such that ending the task also kills the program?

If the program is started by calling a desktop link (.lnk) to the executable, in the link set it to run minimized.

@DrMoishePippik I don't even want it to be minimized. I want it not visible.

When you work with TaskScheduler, you basically have two options.
Either

The program runs in the user scope under the user's rights, and that spawns a visible application, or...

The program runs outside of the user's right, for example as system, and its completely invisible to the user, and the program cannot be interacted with.


There is no middle ground.
You can create a 2nd user, log in with it, then switch user to your own user, and have Task Scheduler start the task as the 2nd user, that way the task will run in interactive mode, but you don't see it.
The downside of this approach is that you always manually need to login twice when the computer starts, and also manually have to sign out the 2nd user before turning off the computer.
It would be better to find out why your program doesn't work under SYSTEM, fix that, then run it as user NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM, or use the option, whether or not the user is signed in, and ensure that it works there.
A few things to note, if your program needs a network share to be mounted, that network share may not be availalbe to the program. You need to create a batch file that mounts the network share and then runs your program, and call the batch file from TaskScheduler.
Keep in mind that the SYSTEM user will not be able to connect to network shares at all.
